# xarray.open_mfdataset for a small subset of variables

Tags: python-xarray

I'm trying to read a timeseries of a single [WRF](https://www.mmm.ucar.edu/weather-research-and-forecasting-model) output variable.  The time series is distributed, one timestamp per file, across more than 5000 netCDF files.  Each file contains roughly 200 variables.

Is there a way to call xarray.open_mfdataset() for only the variable I'm interested in?  I can specify a single variable by providing a list to the  'data_vars' argument, but it still reads everything for the 'minimal' case.  For my files the 'minimal' case includes almost everything and is thus relatively slow.

Is my best bet to create a single netCDF file containing my variable of interest with something like [ncrcat](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#Concatenation), or is there a more streamlined way to do this entirely within xarray (or some other python tool)?

My netCDF files are netCDF4 (not netCDF4-classic), which seems to rule out [netCDF4.MFDataset()](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.MFDataset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why providing the `data_vars=` argument still reads all data - I experienced the same issue reading WRF output.  My workaround was to make a list of all the variables I didn't need (all 200+) and feed that to the `drop_variables=` argument. You can get a list of all variables and then just delete or comment out the ones you want to keep.

```
varlist = list(ds.variables)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That hadn't occurred to me, and does speed up the reading somewhere between 25 and 50% in my not-very-scientific testing.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define a preprocessing function that defines the variables to keep via the "preprocess" keyword argument, e.g.:

```
preprocess=lambda ds: ds[variablelist]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up for the ones who will find this thread later.
Based on the documentation (but a bit hidden), the "data_vars=" argument only works with Python 3.9.